# Calling a method inside of an IBAction method not sending what is expected

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit

Both methods (one that acts when keyboard return is pressed and one where a button is pressed) call the same method but the one with the IBAction (the button) is not sending the correct NSString to the method.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
if([textInput text].length > 0){
    [self sendMessage:[textInput text]];
    return YES;
}
return NO;
}

- (IBAction)sendButtonClicked:(id)sender {
    if([textInput text].length > 0){
        NSLog(@"%@ shouldve been", [textInput text]);
        [self sendMessage:[textInput text]];
    }
}

-(void) sendMessage:(NSString*) message{
    NSLog(@"Message sent: %@", message);
    [textInput resignFirstResponder];
    [textInput setText:@""];

}
```

I am not sure what's going on here.

I am getting when I click on the button!

```
2016-01-02 18:21:37.570 ChatSystem[24369:1848562] Message sent: <UIButton: 0x7f8f98c44cd0; frame = (333 4; 34 29); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x7f8f98c45240>>
```

It works fine when I hit return on the keyboard though. Both run-throughs have the same text input!

Comment: What is `textInput`?

Comment: It is just a UITextField

Comment: How is it declared? How is it assigned? Are you sure it is set properly when the `sendButtonClicked:` method is called?

Comment: textInput is connected to ViewController.h with Interface Builder. The "send" button is connected as well with the name "sendButton."

Comment: do u hit return method first? or button first ?

Comment: if u hit return first and then button next, then the button method will not be executed as, text.length >0 will be false

Comment: The return button wasn't hit. I only typed some test string then hit the button.

Comment: how did u typed the string before u hit the button ? Show code related to the other delegate methods of textfield

Comment: Is the code in your question the real actual code copy and pasted from your project?

Comment: Yes. It is the exact code.

Comment: I invoke the First Responder by clicking on the UITextField then typed something on simulator. Then I clicked the button.

Comment: show the code related to shouldChangeCharacterInrange method @Lucky

Comment: ok, when u type something in simulator is the keyboard is visible to you ?

Comment: I have shown the complete code there

Comment: looks like you haven't set the textfield delegate. Have u set the delegate ? @Lucky

Comment: Did you connect the action of the button to `sendButtonClicked:` or `sendMessage:`?